# Facebook Graph API comment from unavailable

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook app which manages a user's page.

I am making requests using the facebook's javascript SDK, and makign a GET request at the following (with page access token of course):

```
pageID?fields=posts{comments{from,message}}
```

This returns a list of post comments and messages, as well as information about the users that posted the comments, or so I thought.
During my testing I've been making posts and comments as both the page and as myself (admin) and in both cases the `from` returned a value, however yesterday a friend of mine added a comment to one of the posts, and when reading his comment i can get the message, but there is no indication of the `from` value, it is not present.

Am I doing something wrong or is it not possible to get these? I've seen one more post on SO about this, though in that post it clearly states that if you have a token, you should be able to see this info, yet I do not.

Comment: The changelog mentions that this has been removed for comments in group posts, but is not really clear about whether that’s the same for pages now. There’s also several bug reports where people are discussing this with the FB engineers, maybe join in on one of those, like f.e. https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/441085432981903

Comment: Thanks will look into it. Seems really weird that I cannot see who posted something on my page via API, whilst I can perfectly see it through regular GUI on the page itself, makes it really hard to make apps that manage facebook page's posts / comments